# Change color in unity c# gradually

Tags: unity-game-engine, colors

Ok so, I have a small fighting game, and I want to have the saturation slowly decrease as I hit the dummy more to show their health.

The only way I can think to describe it is like using -= on a Color.

Here's all I've got and it doesn't work besides changing it once.

```
 private void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D collision)
{
    if (collision.collider.tag == "hurtbox")
      {
        Debug.Log("hit");
        collision.gameObject.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().color = new Color(100f, 5f, 5f);
      }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

The easiest way to accomplish this is to use a [Gradient](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Gradient.html). Then upon taking damage, calculate the timepoint in the gradient using your maxhealth and currenthealth (assuming you have those).

You can then set the gradient values in the inspector.

Example;

```
public Gradient Gradient;

public float MaxHealth = 100f;
public SpriteRenderer SpriteRenderer;
private float currentHealth { get; set; }


private void Start()
{
    currentHealth = MaxHealth;
}

public void TakeDamage(float amount)
{
    currentHealth -= amount; 
    float timePoint = currentHealth / MaxHealth;
    Color color = Gradient.Evaluate(timePoint);
    SpriteRenderer.color = color;
}
```

Comment: i wasnt able to get this to work :(

it showed an error anytime i used the ".Evalutate", would you know why? do i need to import something?

Comment: Well without seeing your new code or errors it is hard to say what you did wrong. The only using you need is the UnityEngine one

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using Color.Lerp?

Try replacing your code with something similar to this:

```
private void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D collision)
{
    if (collision.collider.tag == "hurtbox")
        Debug.Log("hit");
    otherSpriteRenderer = collision.gameObject.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>()
    otherSpriteRenderer.color = Color.Lerp (otherSpriteRenderer.color, Color.red, 0.005f); 
}
```

otherSpriteRenderer refers to the sprite render attatched to the object you are colliding with

Here is the unity documentation: https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Color.Lerp.html?_ga=2.138410096.1930692520.1591664984-2127613969.1584173609